# jQuery change function only for closest element

Tags: jquery, html

i use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".productselector").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find("option:selected").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "value1") {
            $(".mini1").slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $(".mini1").slideUp();
        }
});
});
});
```

with the HTML

```
<div id="no1" style="display:block">
<div class="form-group">
<label>1. Item</label>

 <select class="productselector"/>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="value1"> Item A </option>
<option value="value2"> Item B </option>
</select>
</div>
<span class="mini1" style=" display: none;">text</span>

</div>
<div id="no2" style="display:block">
<div class="form-group">
   <label>2. Item</label>
<select class="productselector"/>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="value1"> Item A </option>
<option value="value2"> Item B </option>
</select>
</div>
<span class="mini1" style=" display: none;">text</span>
</div>
```

If i change one of the select fields to "Item A" i want the "text" to show up directly under the select field i just used and not under both. Looks like the

```
.closest('.form-group')
```

has no effect...? [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nanni/44w3n1k6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
UPD:

```
$(function() {
    $(".productselector").on('change', function() {
       var val = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
       var $span = $(this).closest(".form-group").parents('div').find('.mini1');
       if (val == "value1") $span.slideDown();
       else $span.slideUp();        
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/44w3n1k6/12/

Comment: I edited my text a little bit so maybe it is clearer now what i am looking for. Your proposal only works for the first select field.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer, please see this option.

Comment: Thanks very much that works and i hopefully did understand how to apply  .closest() properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is these lines,

```
$(".mini1").slideDown(); 
$(".mini1").slideUp();
```

Both classes are named mini1 so they both show. You need to select the right one